# Seed MATLAB `idinput`

Tags: matlab, random

The generation of two PRBS signals using the `idinput` function of the System Identification toolbox in MATLAB results in two times the same sequence. How can I randomize the second sequence with respect to the first? Can I set a seed or something?

```
u1 = idinput(N,'prbs');
u2 = idinput(N,'prbs');

all(u1==u2) % Returns 1
```

I have tried to seed the MATLAB rng

```
rng(12345)
```

Or set the GlobalStream

```
s = RandStream('mcg16807','Seed',1234)
RandStream.setGlobalStream(s)
```

Which was of no effect.

Comment: I think you need to generate a `u2` of different length than `u1` and then crop it. Try that.

Comment: Thanks Ander, this does however not work (a sequence of length N+1 is in the first N elements equal to a sequence of length N). I would however rather use a documented and well-defined method in my code.

Comment: Oh well sorry. Some binary number generators change the output with the length change